# pyside QGraphicsScene: Why it is not working?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am new to Qt and PySyde. I trying to create a small app to visualize sime line drawings.
In order to do that I try to use QGraphicsView an QGraphicsScene. I made a test to learn how it is working but it isn't. I googled a lot around, I do not understan why it isn't working.
Can somebody explain me the reason and bring me the light?

My code (just want to put a line and a sample text on the scene):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        leftpanel=QtGui.QFrame()
        leftpanel.setGeometry(0,0,300,400)
        scene=QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        scene.addText("Hello, world!")
        view=QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene,leftpanel)
        view.setSceneRect(0,0,300,400)
        pen=QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black,2)
        scene.addLine(0,0,200,200,pen)
        hbox.addWidget(leftpanel)
        rightpanel=QtGui.QFrame()
        hbox.addWidget(rightpanel)
        szoveg=QtGui.QLabel(rightpanel)
        szoveg.setText(u"Hello World!")
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.resize(500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('blabla')
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save reference to scene somewhere, e.g. in `Example` instance:

```
def initUI(self):
    # ...
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    self.scene = scene  # save reference to scene, or it will be destroyed
    scene.addText("Hello, world!")
    # ...
```

In another function, you'll be able to add more items to the scene:

```
def anotherFunction(self):     
    self.scene.addText("Another Hello, world!")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the scene does not displayed either. I think the graphicview does not connected to the scene, but it should be, because in this line view=QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene,leftpanel) I provide the constuctor the scene and the parent. Here the documentation says it is possible: http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsScene.html#PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsScene

Comment: @sipiatti, Have you tried? It works for me when reference to scene is saved. full code with fix: http://pastebin.com/cBy2y8rq . Scene does not displayed because Python garbage collector deletes it when `initUI` returns.

Comment: @reclosedev. This looks like a bug (or unexpected behaviour) in PySide. Strictly speaking, it should not be necessary to save a reference in this particular case (although I'm not actually recommending that). The way the code is written, all the objects _should_ become connected together in a hierarchy via parenting (which is why it works with PyQt4). Alternative fix: `scene=QtGui.QGraphicsScene(leftpanel)`.

Comment: @reclosedev thanks for your effort, it works. On the other hand it should work with parenting so it could be a bug in PySide as ekhumoro told. If I create the GraphicsView first, and after I set its scene by the setScene method it works in PySide also. Anyway, I accept your answer as it solves the situation.

Comment: @sipiatti, yes it's very strange behaviour.